# Using rpy2 in Jpyter lab v Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have an R code block in a jupyter notebook that works fine, by using:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

But when I try to run the same notebook in jupyter lab, I get this error message:

```
Unable to determine R home: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R'
```

And

```
ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation
```

Running !pip freeze in a new notebook in jupyter lab shows rpy2==3.5.4 in the list. But if I run python -m rpy2.situation in terminal in jupyterlab, it says no module found.

Comment: What about adding the magic `%pip` version in your `pip freeze`? I think you have an environment issue in that JupyterLab runs in a different environment and you aren't addressing it. `%pip install` works to target installations done inside a Jupyter notebook to the exact environment that the kernel underlying notebook is using. And so it may be worth trying `%pip freeze` and see what that reflects. The exclamation point doesn't do that, see [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).